# Setting a delegate for a NSManaged Object

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm having issues setting the delegate of a Core Data object to a certain view controller I have.  I'm getting and error which leads me to believe it's not synthesizing the accessor methods:

```
2012-06-23 18:21:20.566 App[34164:12803] -[NSManagedObject setSyncDelegate:]:    unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x907cf30
2012-06-23 18:21:20.567 App[34164:12803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject setSyncDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x907cf30'
```

The NSManagedObject, SavedPhoto, has the following .h:

```
@interface SavedPhoto : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fileName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<SyncPhotoDelegate> syncDelegate;

@end
```

and .m:

```
@implementation SavedPhoto

@dynamic fileName;
@synthesize syncDelegate = _syncDelegate;

@end
```

And I'm trying to set the delegate in a view controller like so:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
SavedPhoto *savedPhoto = (SavedPhoto *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SavedPhoto" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[savedPhoto setSyncDelegate:self];
```

Where "self" is a view controller that implements the protocol SyncPhotoDelegate.  Is it even possible to have a synthesized property in an NSManagedObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the instance is not actually one of your class. I would check your model file to make sure it is configured properly. Notice in your console output that it says `[NSManagedObject setSyncDelegate:]` and *not* `[SavedPhoto
 setSyncDelegate:]`

Comment: That is an interesting observation.  I do have an explicit cast of SavedPhoto prior to

`SavedPhoto *savedPhoto = (SavedPhoto *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SavedPhoto" inManagedObjectContext:context];`

Also, I tested `[savedPhoto setFileName:@"foo"]` and that seemed to work, so it has some of the accessor methods set correctly.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was that "syncDelegate" is in effect a transient attribute.  As such, I needed to actually include it not just in the class file SavedPhoto, but the data model (.xcdatamodeld) as well by adding the attribute "syncDelegate" with as an undefined, transient attribute.

Comment: Is the instance now one of your class? I mean, you might get things working for stuff that the runtime can convert to key-value coding, but it may be worth tracking down. Casting is not enough at runtime to get you a proper instance of your class; it just allows code to compile which speaks that class's interface, if that makes sense. You can configure which class an entity gets returned as in Xcode's model editor in the right-hand pane.

Comment: Actually, it was still of NSManagedObject, but it still managed to work even at runtime.  With your comment though, I set it correctly to be an instance of SavedPhoto, so I think my code is even more correct and preventing future errors.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, Apple has done a pretty good job with converting a *lot* of this stuff at runtime with key-value coding, so we don't always see exactly why something is working. Always feels better to have the types you expect!